# How to loop array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to add an object to JavaScript array and then loop it.But loop is not running

```js
    var basicConf = {
    RootUrl: "https://api.joltcomm.com/",
    username: 'test',
    password: 'test',
    APPURL:'https://dev.joltcomm.com/secureadmin/',
    PROJECTID:'',
    uData:'',
    iFunc:[],
    pushData:function(data){
        this.iFunc.push(data);
    }
    };
    function onProjectLoad(fn,params)
    {
        basicConf.pushData({'function':fn,'parameters':params});
    }
    onProjectLoad("getData",["user-project/2","showProjects",1]);

    $.each(basicConf.iFunc, function( index, value ) {
        console.log(value);
    var fn=value.function+'(';
        $.each(value.parameters, function( i, v ) {
            if(i>0)
            {
                fn+=',';

            }
            fn+='"'+v+'"';
        });
        fn+=');';
        console.log(fn);
       eval(fn);
    });
```

I am not getting into the loop I don’t know why

Comment: Did you want `iFunc` to be an array? `iFunc:[],`

Comment: @AntP no. I want to use this an object

Comment: Then you can't. You can only "push" to an array. You can *assign* a new object to `iFunc` though: `this.iFunc = data;`.

Comment: then how will it add another object then?

Comment: It won't. If you want to do that you need an array.

Comment: I downvoted your question (and voted to close it) because it is not even remotely clear what you are trying to do. Your question is "how can I add an object to an object," which doesn't even make sense.

Comment: `this.iFunc[Object.keys(this.iFunc).length] = data;` - going by the amount of crap code floating about the interweb I'm guessing you're after this structure: `{0: ..., 1: ...}`, but this is really an XY problem.  Since ***everyone*** has said you should be using an array, you should take note.

Comment: eval() is a bad bad bad practice. And when you update the question from the original, you really should notify the people that took time to answer your question.

Comment: @epascarello i want to call funtions dynamically. What i want is to get all functions details first like function name and parameters and store them to a variable then i want to execute them all by calling a function

Comment: There are better ways of doing it than eval() and your code runs. Not sure what fails with the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Well it is hard to push items to an object.

```
iFunc:{},  <-- object
```

you want an array if you actually want to add them to an array.

```
iFunc:[],   //<-- That is an array, you can push to the array
```

If you just want to update the object, than do not use push.

---

```js
var basicConf = {
    RootUrl: "https://api.example.com/",
    username: 'test',
    password: 'test',
    APPURL:'https://dev.example.com/example/',
    PROJECTID:'',
    uData:'',
    iFunc:[],
    pushData:function(data){
        this.iFunc.push(data);
        console.log(this.iFunc)
    }
};
function onProjectLoad(fn,params)
{
    basicConf.pushData({'function':fn,'parameters':params});
}
onProjectLoad("getData",["user-project/2","showProjects",1]);
```

Comment: yes i added it in an array but was unable to loop it

Comment: Loop what? Where is your loop?

Answer (score 0):

[`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) is an array method, you can't 'push' new things into an object as you need to provide a key to store the data against.

```
addData:function(data){
  this.iFunc.someKey = data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

indeed you can't push key/val on an object directly but you can set them in an array-way approach:

```
var basicConf = {
    RootUrl: "https://api.example.com/",
    username: 'test',
    password: 'test',
    APPURL:'https://dev.example.com/example/',
    PROJECTID:'',
    uData:'',
    iFunc:{},
    pushData:function(data){
        for (key in data) {
            this.iFunc[key] = data[key];
        }
    }
};
function onProjectLoad(fn,params)
{
    basicConf.pushData({'function':fn,'parameters':params});
}

onProjectLoad("getData",["user-project/2","showProjects",1]);
```

so if you console.log your basicConf, it will be like:

```
iFunc: Object
function: "getData"
parameters: Array[3]
    0: "user-project/2"
    1: "showProjects"
    2: 1
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you need. A method to extend an existing object with additional values.

```js
var basicConf = {
  RootUrl: "https://api.example.com/",
  username: 'test',
  password: 'test',
  APPURL: 'https://dev.example.com/example/',
  PROJECTID: '',
  uData: '',
  iFunc: {},
  pushData: function(data) {
    this.iFunc.push(data);
  }
};

function onProjectLoad(fn, params) {
  extend(basicConf, {
    'function': fn,
    'parameters': params
  });

}
onProjectLoad("getData", ["user-project/2", "showProjects", 1]);



function extend(dest, src) {
  var keys = Object.keys(src);
  var i = 0;
  while (i < keys.length) {
    if (!this.extend || (this.extend && dest[keys[i]] === undefined)) {
      dest[keys[i]] = src[keys[i]];
    }
    i++;
  }
  return dest;
}
```